# if $(m+n)^2/(4m(m-n)^2+4)$ is integer then it is a square number

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Let $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$. If the number  $$ k=\dfrac{(m+n)^2}{4m(m-n)^2+4}$$ is an integer, then prove that $k$ is a perfect square.

I have countered this by first assuming $t=m-n$. Then some simplifications leads me to this quadratic equation;
$$(4k-1)t^2+(2kn-2n)t+(k-n^2)=0$$In order to have a integer solution for $t$ the discriminant should be a perfect square. Then I am stuck . I was trying to come up with an expression of the form $kl=x^2$ where gcd$(k,l)=1$. Then it will follow that $k$ is a square. But I can't figure it out. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I think you messed up the simplification. $t = m-n$ gives you $$k = \frac{(t +2n)^2}{4(t + n)t^2 + 4}$$ which is cubic in $t$, not quadratic.

Comment: ohh,yes,,thanks...but still having problem..any ideas how to approach this?....

Comment: One thing that you can note is that unless $m = n = 0$ (a trivial case), we have $k \ge 1$, which you can manipulate into a cubic polynomial in $t$ with positve leading coefficient being $\le 0$. This gives an upper limit for the size of $t$ with respect to $n$, and since $m \ge 0$, we have that $t \ge -n$ for a lower limit. So you only need to prove that values of $t$ in that range lead to $k$ being a perfect square.

Comment: can you please post your full solution? ..@PaulSinclair

Comment: If I had a full solution, I would. But I've just played with it a bit on the side of doing other things. Based on what I said before, I believe that you can show $m \le \max\{n, 3\}$, but I haven't checked that, so I may have it wrong.